# How to deploy to a single specific server using Capistrano

Tags: deployment, capistrano, release-management

I have a system in production that has several servers in several roles. I would like to test a new app server by deploying to that specific server, without having to redeploy to every server in production. Is there a way to ask Capistrano to deploy to a specific server? Ideally I'd like to be able to run something like

```
cap SERVER=app2.example.com ROLE=app production deploy
```

if I just wanted to deploy to app2.example.com.

Thanks!

[update]
I tried the solution suggested by wulong by executing:

```
cap HOSTS=app2.server.hostname ROLE=app qa deploy
```

but capistrano seemed be trying to execute tasks for other roles on that server in addition to app tasks. Maybe I need to update my version of cap (I'm running v2.2.0)?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I ended up posting a question on the capistrano users list [here](http://groups.google.com/group/capistrano/browse_thread/thread/592ab63dda72d7e), and got the following response from Jamis (edited a bit by me here for clarity):

---

Try the HOSTS environment variable:

```
cap HOSTS=app2.example.com production deploy
```

Note that doing this will treat app2 as being in every role, not just
whichever role(s) it happens to be declared in.

If what you want is to do a regular deploy, but only act on app2, and
only as app2 is declared in your recipe file, you can use the HOSTFILTER
variable instead:

```
cap HOSTFILTER=app2.example.com production deploy
```

[...]

Consider this concrete example. Suppose your
script defines three servers, A, B, and C. And it defines a task, "foo",
that (by default) wants to run on A and B, but not C. Like this:

```
role :app, "A", "B"
role :web, "C"

task :foo, :roles => :app do
  run "echo hello"
end
```

Now, if you do `cap foo`, it will run the echo command on both A and B.

If you do `cap HOSTS=C foo`, it will run the echo command on C,
regardless of the :roles parameter to the task.

If you do `cap HOSTFILTER=C foo`, it will not run the echo command at
all, because the intersection of (A B) and (C) is an empty set. (There
are no hosts in foo's host list that match C.)

If you do `cap HOSTFILTER=A foo`, it will run the echo command on only
A, because (A B) intersected with (A) is (A).

Lastly, if you do `cap HOSTFILTER=A,B,C foo`, it will run the echo
command on A and B (but not C), because (A B) intersected with (A B C)
is (A B).

To summarize: HOSTS completely overrides the hosts or roles declaration
of the task, and forces everything to run against the specified host(s).
The HOSTFILTER, on the other hand, simply filters the existing hosts
against the given list, choosing only those servers that are already in
the tasks server list.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work anymore with Capistrano 3.4

Comment: In Capistrano 3, you'll use the HOSTS environment variable for what HOSTFILTER is in Capistrano 2. http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/host-filtering/

Answer (score 3):

The following should work out of the box:

```
cap HOSTS=app2.example.com ROLE=app deploy
```

If you want to deploy to >1 server with the same role:

```
cap HOSTS=app2.example.com,app3.example.com,app4.example.com ROLE=app deploy
```

Comment: I tried the first case (deploying to a single app server) by executing
cap HOSTS=app2.server.hostname ROLE=app qa deploy
but capistrano seemed be trying to execute tasks for other roles on that server in addition to app tasks. Maybe I need to update my version of cap (I'm running 2.2.0).

Comment: HOSTFILTER is the answer, this is not what u want.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem and tried the following. It works:

```
cap production ROLES=web HOSTS=machine1 stats
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this in deploy.rb:

```
task :production do
  if ENV['SERVER'] && ENV['ROLE']
    role ENV['ROLE'], ENV['SERVER']
  else
    # your full config
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also specifiy task-level hosts parameter this way:

```
task :ship_artifacts, :hosts => ENV['DEST_HOST']  do

end
```