# Capistrano: running cap deploy:install ROLES=role1 runs ALL tasks on role1 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have a capistrano deployment setup that simplified looks something like this:

```
server "server_ip1", :role1
server "server_ip2", :role2
```

And a pair of tasks

```
namespace :postgresql do
  desc "Install necessary ubuntu packages"
  task :install, roles: [:role2] do
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install postgresql libpq-dev"
  end
  after "deploy:install", "postgresql:install"
end

namespace :app_install do
  desc "Install necessary ubuntu packages"
  task :install, roles: [:role1, :role2] do
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install imagemagick"
  end
  after "deploy:install", "app_install:install"
end
```

Now the problem is if I run `cap deploy:install ROLES=role1` it correctly runs the tasks on server_ip1 BUT it runs BOTH task app_install:install AND postgresql:install

And the funny thing is if I run `cap deploy:install` (without ROLES=role1) it does everything 'correctly'.

Am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem [How to deploy to a single specific server using Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429816/how-to-deploy-to-a-single-specific-server-using-capistrano)