# How to create roles and run capistrano tasks for specific roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, roles, role

Here is my production.rb in config/deploy

```
Instance Details
server '198.61.179.237', :web, :app, :db, primary: true
server '198.61.228.160', :file_server

# Rails Environment
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

And from deploy.rb

```
namespace :check do
  task :function_1, :roles => :web do
    puts 'function_1'
  end
  task :function_2, :roles => :file_server do
    puts 'filesssss'
  end
end
```

But when I try doing

```
cap HOSTS=198.61.228.160 production check:function_2
cap HOSTS=198.61.228.160 production check:function_1

cap HOSTS=198.61.179.237 production check:function_2
cap HOSTS=198.61.179.237 production check:function_1
```

Everyone of them gives respective output. But as per the declaration

`function_1` should work only for `:role => :web` and similarly `function_2` should work only for `:role => :file_server`.

Where I am going wrong ?
What is the correct way to approach ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is `cap HOSTFILTER=198.61.228.160 function_2` or `cap HOSTFILTER=198.61.179.237 function_1`

It's because the HOSTFILTER checks for the intersect of all the servers with the functions role and the server you're looking for. A great explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429816/how-to-deploy-to-a-single-specific-server-using-capistrano) by [Pete Hodgson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53529/pete-hodgson)

Also we can see this because of the manual:

```
    $ cap -H

       HOSTS
            Execute the tasks against this comma-separated list of hosts.
            Effectively, this makes the host(s) part of every roles.

       HOSTFILTER
            Execute tasks against this comma-separated list of host, 
            but only if the host has the proper role for the task.

       HOSTROLEFILTER
            Execute tasks against the hosts in this comma-separated list of roles,
            but only if the host has the proper role for the task.

       ROLES
            Execute tasks against this comma-separated list of roles.  Hosts which
            do not have the right roles will be skipped.
```